# Querying in-memory mongodb with Jest

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to unit test my code, I am using Node.js, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose and trying to test it with Jest.

I am having issues with the in-memory mongo db with Jest. I have read the documentation (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb).

When trying to test a query for one of my Mongoose models, I believe that my query is not pointing at the correct place, I would like it to run its query against the in-memory collection.

My current test setup:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const Preferences = require("./preferences");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

describe("Preference helper function", () => {
  let connection;
  let db;
  let userPreferences;

  const testUser = new Preferences({
    userId: ObjectId("5eef15429e93464b3ccae235"),
    wordPreferences: [
      { wordId: 1, active: true},
      { wordId: 2, active: true},
      { wordId: 3, active: true},
      { wordId: 4, active: true},
      { wordId: 5, active: true}
    ],
  });

  beforeAll(async () => {
    connection = await MongoClient.connect(global.__MONGO_URI__, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    });
    db = await connection.db(global.__MONGO_DB_NAME__);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await connection.close();
    await db.close();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    userPreferences = await db.collection("userPreferences");
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await userPreferences.deleteMany();
  });

  it("get active words function gives correct result", async () => {
    await userPreferences.insertOne(testUser);
    const expectedResult = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let queryResult = await Preferences.getActiveWordIds(testUser.userId);
    expect(queryResult).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

Running this code gives the following error:
`Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error`

Changing the timeout for this does not resolve the problem as it appears the query does not resolve. Here is the the Moongoose model for the Preference model used in the test above:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PreferenceMappingSchema = require("../preference-mapping");

var PreferenceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  wordPreferences: {
    type: [PreferenceMappingSchema],
    required: true,
  },
});

// Choose the correct db and set the model
const db = mongoose.connection.useDb("users");
const Preferences = (module.exports = db.model("Preference", PreferenceSchema));

module.exports.getActiveWordIds = async function(userId) {
  try {
    const user = await Preferences.aggregate([
        // Get the current users doc
      { $match: { userId: userId} },
      {
        $project: {
          wordPreferences: {
            // Get only active words
            $filter: {
              input: "$wordPreferences",
              as: "pref",
              cond: {
                $eq: ["$$pref.active", true],
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }
    ]).exec();
    // Map to list of valid numbers
    return user[0]['wordPreferences'].map(x => x.wordId);
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error);
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Mongo and Mongoose connections are unrelated, there's no way how Mongoose could be aware of Mongo connection in your code. userPreferences.insertOne is pending promise that waits for a connection. Don't use raw Mongo when you use Mongoose, that's it.